How to translate "walk it off" into Latin? As the phrase corresponds to relieving physical pain
The best translation I could figure was "Ambulate donec discesserit."
But that would be more like, "walk until it will have departed." Is there a more efficient and/or precise way to translate this phrase?

Can you add some more context to tell us more about what you have in mind by "walk it off"? Do you mean walking to relieve physical pain, like from a mild injury during a soccer game? Or walking to take your mind off something or let an intense emotion cool down so you can think straight? Or something else?

Walk it off as it corresponds to relieving physical pain.

"Walk it off" is a phrase commonly used by coaches or team mates to encourge someone who is experiencing pain due to a minor injury during a game. It is US slang.

I came up with two suggestions. First, this: Ambula et tolera
That's the imperative form of verbs meaning "walk" and "endure."
I like the internal alliteration provided by the 'l' in each word, and also the rhythm the phrase gets from the equal number of syllables on either side of 'et': Am-bu-la et tol-er-a.
The imperative structure also reflects the nature of the original phrase, which is uniformly delivered with a macho affect (e.g., "Be a man and walk it off!")
...and, secondly, this:
Ambulare est evadere!
On one level, a truism--why, yes, to walk is to escape, albeit slowly--but on another level this is advice given without mentioning the thing to be evaded, which is of course, pain. Athletes do not mention pain.

Does this phrase, especially the use of ambulare in this way, have any textual attestations? Even though ambulare does mean "walk", the verb in question is "to walk [x] off", which I feel must be different from ambulare. The action of walking isn't what's at play here, but rather the working through pain by continuing onward.

I like tolera. Maybe combine it with another verb. I'm not sure whether ambula works. Maybe perdura? I can't help but feel there must be a better way to say this.
